# Lock wait timeout exceeded in JPA because of two OneToMany relationships to the same table

Tags: jpa

I think the reason is in wrong description in the relations, so I will try to explain it. 
I have 5 tables. 3 entity tables and two join tables:

article, branch ,photo, article_photo, branch_photo

And now the relations between tables:

between branch and article

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="branch", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

between branch and photo with join table branch_photo:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER ,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "branch_photo", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "photo_id"))
```

between article and photo with join table article_photo:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER ,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinTable(name="article_photo", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="photo_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
```

So when I try to persist branch without the last relation between article and photo it's working but if the relation is there then timeout exception is thrown:

```
javax.el.ELException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Error Code: 1205
Call: INSERT INTO photo (blobkey, blobthumb) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [null, null]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Photo [id=0])
```

The question is why the transaction that is writing to the photo table cannot finish? Why there is may be other transaction trying to write in table photo but photo that is for article? (I do not create any article or any photo for article, but only photo  for branch) How to describe the relation between these tables so that there is not lock?
Thank you!